# Jekyll export SASS vars to Javascript vars

Tags: javascript, sass, jekyll, jekyll-extensions

I have a project (UI Kit just like Bootstrap) build with **Jekyll** and **Jekyll-Assets** and I'm trying to understand if it is possible to create either a **Jekyll** plugin or a **Jekyll-Assets** plugin in order to dumb all **SASS** vars from a `_variables.scss` file into an object var in a **Javascript** file. The idea would be to convert:

```
// _variables.scss
$white: #FFF;
$black: #000;
$red: #FF0;
```

into

```
// _variables.js
(function(){

    window.appVars = {
       white: '#FFF',
       black: '#000',
       red: '#FF0'
    }

})();
```

Worth mentioning that this converted javascript file will later be imported into other javascript files through the **Jekyll-Assets** build process:

```
// app.js
//= include _variables.js
console.log (window.appVars);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a plugin to do this.
The simplest way is to pass jekyll variables to sass and js files.

#### Jekyll variables

Here, I use configuration variables from *_config.yml*, but you can also use variables from a _data file.

```
# _config.yml
custom_vars:
  text_color: red
  background_color: '#ddd'
```

#### Sass files

In standard jekyll setup there is a bootstrap file assets/main.css that imports everything it needs.
It seems that you cannot @import sass files containing a front matter and variables, so, you have to grab your variables in your boostrap file before @import statment.

```
// assets/main.css
{%- for var in site.custom_vars %}
${{ var[0] }}: {{ var [1] }};
{%- endfor %}
@import "whatever";
```

#### Js files

Instruct jekyll to process you file by adding a front matter :

```
---
---
// assets/script.js
(function(){
    window.appVars = {
        {%- for var in site.custom_vars %}
          {{ var[0] }}: '{{ var [1] }}'
          {%- unless forloop.last %},{% endunless %}
        {%- endfor %}
    }
})();
```

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your help and sorry for the delay on my feedback. Your answer is great when it comes to centralise all vars at Jekyll level and then dumb it on any file. Unfortunately in my case, and I might have not explained the issue correctly, I need to have these vars processed so that I can obtain the results like: `$color-master-light:mix($color-master, #FFF, 16%) !default;` or `$table-border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07) !default;`or even `$var-1: 1; $var-2: $var-1 + 2;`

Comment: You have variable name in `{{ var[0] }}` and variable value in `{{ var[1] }}`. I don't understand what's not working.

Comment: David, if I simply dumb everything as a string into the file then a value like `mix($color-master, #FFF, 16%)` will cause javascript to launch an error because it will not know what to do with it. On the other hand I need the methods/functions of the SASS file "parsed" (as in calculated and not transformed into CSS) so that all logic is taken into account.